# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 CTP 2 intellisense via ko-vs-editor for a javascript viewModel but not working?

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, kendo-mvvm

been trying to get working the latest visual studio 2013 feature of the knockout ko-vs-editor intellisense here.

```
<!-- ko-vs-editor viewModel: {"intellisenseMe": "urraa"} --> 
    <div data-bind="text: i"> **no intellisense support here :(** </div>
<!-- /ko-vs-editor -->
```

- Important to note that, I have not installed the knockout framework here, because I am using Kendo MVVM.
- Also using Razor with MVC 4.

Wonder if the intellisense feature has dependency on a particular nugget package of Knockout, MVC version or View Engine???